# Why can't I open "Terminal" in Wily?

Tags: gnome-terminal, 15.10

I've just installed Wily (fresh install, but with shared boot partition and using existing home directory) and am not able to launch "Terminal" ("XTerm" works though). The same problem arises if I use the guest account.

When entering "term" and selecting "Terminal" in dash I only get a spinning wheel and nothing more happens. And when entering `gnome-terminal` in `xterm` I get

```
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
```

I've also tried to remove `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal` and logged out and ind as suggested somewhere.

I've also checked `org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings` in `dconf-editor` and it's reverted to default. I've noted an entry in `/var/log/syslog` that might be relevant:

```
Nov  7 11:23:44 europa org.gnome.Terminal[15084]: Non UTF-8 locale (ISO-8859-1) is not supported!
```

How can I further trouble-shoot this?

As requested I did some more tries and diagnostics. Both `gnome-terminal.real` and `gnome-terminal.wrapper` returned the same error message, and `locale` gives:

```
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=en_US:
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=
```

I normally don't bother modifying the locale, and haven't done so this time either, just selected US langage when installed (I think).

Comment: try `gnome-terminal.real` and `gnome-terminal.wrapper`

Comment: oh, and take a look at `locale` is it set correctly?